# How to create variable of dtype cl.cltypes.uint2 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, pyopencl

I need to create variable with type `cl.cltypes.uint2` for pyopencl in Python.
Now i have created it this way:

```
key = np.array([(0x01020304, 0x05060708)], dtype=cl.cltypes.uint2)[0]
```

Its definitely dirty hack(  How to create it with more clean way?

this: `key = cl.cltypes.uint2((0x01020304, 0x05060708))`

not works because of error: `'numpy.dtype' object is not callable`

Comment: `np.float32(2)` works because `np.float32` is a class with a callable `init` or `__call__`.  Evidently `cl.cltypes.uint2` does not have that property.  Can you point us to the source of that `dtype`?  But even with builtin dtypes, I view `np.array(12, dtype=np.float32)` to be better than `np.float32(12)`.

Comment: it defines here:
https://github.com/inducer/pyopencl/blob/master/pyopencl/cltypes.py#L64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick read of your link suggests that it is making a compound dtype. With out loading and running it, I think your example is something like

```
In [164]: dt = np.dtype([('x',np.uint16),('y',np.uint16)])                                             
In [165]: np.array([(0x01020304, 0x05060708)], dtype=dt)                                               
Out[165]: array([(772, 1800)], dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
In [166]: dt((0x01020304, 0x05060708))                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-d71cce4777b9> in <module>
----> 1 dt((0x01020304, 0x05060708))

TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable
```

and pulling out one record from the array:

```
In [167]: np.array([(0x01020304, 0x05060708)], dtype=dt)[0]                                            
Out[167]: (772, 1800)
In [168]: _.dtype                                                                                      
Out[168]: dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

A compound `dtype` is never callable.

I think a 0d, 'scalar' array is better than an object created with the dtype function (though they have similar methods).

For a compound dtype:

```
In [228]: v = np.array((0x01020304, 0x05060708), dtype=dt)                                             
In [229]: v                                                                                            
Out[229]: array((772, 1800), dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
In [230]: type(v)                                                                                      
Out[230]: numpy.ndarray
In [231]: v[()]                                                                                        
Out[231]: (772, 1800)
In [232]: type(_)                                                                                      
Out[232]: numpy.void
In [233]: _231.dtype                                                                                   
Out[233]: dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

You can cast such an array to `recarray` and get a `record` object, but I don't think creating these is any easier.

```
In [234]: v.view(np.recarray)                                                                          
Out[234]: 
rec.array((772, 1800),
          dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
In [235]: _.x                                                                                          
Out[235]: array(772, dtype=uint16)
In [238]: v.view(np.recarray)[()]                                                                      
Out[238]: (772, 1800)
In [239]: type(_)                                                                                      
Out[239]: numpy.record
```